# Check if incoming message has a certain text inside the property

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

So I've got this `div` which I would like to show in my `component` template if any of the incoming messages has `TYPE_OTHER`. Since there can be many `TYPE_OTHER` numbers I'm trying to think of some check which would 'see' that part of the property. Not sure how to do that, I guess with some combination of `ngFor` and `ngIf`, but I got lost.

This is my model:

```
export enum MessagesType {
  TYPE_PRIMARY = "TYPE_PRIMARY",
  TYPE_SECONDARY = "TYPE_SECONDARY",
  TYPE_OTHER_1 = "TYPE_OTHER_1",
  TYPE_OTHER_2 = "TYPE_OTHER_2",
  TYPE_OTHER_3 = "TYPE_OTHER_3",
  TYPE_OTHER_4 = "TYPE_OTHER_4",
  TYPE_OTHER_5 = "TYPE_OTHER_5",
  TYPE_OTHER_6 = "TYPE_OTHER_6",
  TYPE_OTHER_7 = "TYPE_OTHER_7",
  TYPE_OTHER_8 = "TYPE_OTHER_8",
  TYPE_OTHER_9 = "TYPE_OTHER_9",
  TYPE_OTHER_10 = "TYPE_OTHER_10",
}
```

Template:

```
<div class="show-if-type-other" *ngIf="
   // message.type --> if it has 'TYPE_OTHER' show this div     
">
  <p>{{ message.type }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `*ngIf="message.type.includes('TYPE_OTHER')">`

Comment: Well that's a nice way to do it. Thank you @micronyks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[includes](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp)** function to check whether the string contains the characters of a specified string.

```
*ngIf="message.type.includes('TYPE_OTHER')">
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```html
<div class="show-if-type-other" *ngIf="message.type.includes('TYPE_OTHER')">    
    <p>{{ message.type }}</p>
</div>
```